# Why doesn't the player as champ have to await the next challenger?

Tags: video-games, pokemon

In Pokémon, especially the games, the player defeats the current champ. After defeating him, the team is registered and the player start... at home. Then the player can roam the country and even defeat the old champ as often as he likes. And he still is in the same place, in the champ room.

**So, is there a in-universe explanantion why the player is allowed to roam freely, while the old champ has to stay put?**

Comment: Is this on-topic ?

Comment: @Kalissar why shouldn't it be on topic? It is a fantasy world... The Pokemon tag already existed.

Comment: @Kalissar - Is a mystical world with talking monsters, magic, scifi devices, time travel and telepathy on-topic? Yes, I think it might be,

Comment: Alright alright ! @Armin are you looking for an in-universe answer or an out-universe one ? The out-universe answer might be "because it would be boring for the player".

Comment: @Kalissar in universe of course xD the out universe is obvious

Comment: Maybe the old champion is a bitter loser.

Comment: @Richard Is it? As it is related to a video game, rather than the series itself, I think it is more at Arcade SE :)

Comment: @dawny33 - Video games (at least **as relates to their plotlines**) are very firmly on-topic here.

Comment: @Richard Is this about the plotline, or rather about the gameplay? Sounds to me like it's asking why the game is designed in this particular way, rather than why the *world* works in that way - but then I know nothing about video games. ([Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/320/31394), for those who haven't seen it.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor ok, i'll add that I want a in universe explanation if one exists.The out of universe is pretty obviuous, the player can't do anything after becoming champ and has to wait for other competitors, boring...

Comment: The existence of a tag does not make a work on-topic. That said, this is absolutely on-topic.

Comment: @phantom42 that was only me arguing that Pokemon itself is on topic.

Comment: The way I see it, League champion is both a title and a job. When you win, you get the title, but you don't have to take the job. For the same reason, I think if a champion (in position) dies / retires, anyone who got the title (that's not many people, I suppose) could, in theory, replace them, with the Elite 4 making the arrangements. But that's just my speculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The player declines the status of champion

According to the [Pokémon wiki](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Champion):

> Once you defeat the Champion, you are recognized as the champion,
>   although in the games the player declines the position and allows the
>   previous Champion to reclaim their spot.

This is unsupported by references, but it is clearly possible, since in *Pokémon Black and White*, N refuses to take the position after having defeated Alder.

In light of this fact, the most sensible explanation for the player being able to go back and defeat the old champion that that they **refused to take the job**.

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is because the quest of the game is not to defeat the league, but rather to complete the Pokédex.

Such quest can't be done if the player is stuck battling for the league after he's defeated it once.

So he'd go "Nope, keep the old champion, I've got other things to do. I'm 10 years old I'm not old enough to work full time for you anyway"

Comment: I think it's analogous to playing against the 'club professional' at a golf course. You don't supplant him if you win.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE. Please condiser taking the [about]. The OP stated in [this comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124475/why-doesnt-the-player-as-champ-have-to-await-the-next-challenger#comment309435_124475) that he wanted an in-universe answer, maybe you could orient this answer more to fit his request ?

Comment: @Kalissar The player *character's* quest and age are true in-universe, no?

Comment: The player's age doesn't matter: in RBY, the rival becomes champ. Not wanting to take the position might be a good reason though.

Comment: @Pwassonne yeah, after reading my reply again that struck me, Red should be underage as well. So let's stick to the "I don't want it" part

Answer (score 3):

### Because it doesn't appear to be an actual rule of being a gym leader.

Both in-game, and in-anime, gym leaders are not absolutely required to sit and wait for challengers.

In most of the games, there is a fetch quest of some sort to get the gym leader to go back to their gym so you can challenge them.

In the anime, Brock and Misty are both gym leaders, who leave their gyms but retain their leadership for a time.

Comment: Gym leaders aren't the same as the champion though, are they?

Comment: I'm not sure, but weren't Misty's sisters also the gym leader? And didn't Brock's father take the position as gym leader?

Comment: True, but I don't see why the rules would really be any different. They're still people who have to live lives beyond just sitting in a gym

Comment: @Armin Yes, but they were both still technically leaders for a time. There have been plenty of other leaders that have left their gyms throughout the anime, if only just to go do random things. It's just early, and I'm blanking on names/specific instances at the moment.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm not completely sure whether gym leaders are the same as the champ. Considering the games, nobody tells the player that he is the gym leader now, but when you defeat the champ, everyone tells you your the champ, so becoming champ is already different than becoming gym leader. Couldn't the stuff, a champ is allowed to do also be different?

Comment: It's possible, but can you honestly think of *any* sport where the champion is required to sit somewhere and just wait for challengers? Boxing world champs are allowed to leave the ring, and even their gyms. World championship teams are allowed to leave their stadiums.